# Why is "Hardware.Sensors" not working - LibreHardwareMonitor C#

Tags: c#, openhardwaremonitor

I am new to utilising LibreHardwareMonitor and was wondering why the following line of code is not working.

> foreach (ISensor sensor in Hardware.Sensors) { ... }

The error states that:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Hardware.Sensors'

I am unsure how to go about fixing this, as I must use this tool to gather the temperature information on the hardware within the PC.

```
private void tabTemps_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Computer c = new Computer
      {
      IsCpuEnabled = true,
      IsGpuEnabled = true,
      IsMemoryEnabled = true,
      IsMotherboardEnabled = true,
      IsControllerEnabled = true,
      IsNetworkEnabled = true,
      IsStorageEnabled = true
   };

   c.Open();
            
   foreach (ISensor sensor in Hardware.Sensors)
   {
      rtbTemps.AppendText($"Sensor: {sensor.Name}, Value: {sensor.Value}");
   }
}
```

Thanks,
nozzy

Comment: The error message seems fairly clear to me - you're trying to call a non-static property just via the type name. Which piece of hardware are you expecting to get the sensors for?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am trying to get the temperatures of all my components, mainly CPU, GPU, MoBo and Liquid Cooler

Comment: I think you may have missed the point of my question. You've just said `Hardware.Sensors`, which is an instance property, i.e. it relates to *one piece of hardware*. You probably need to get a list of `Hardware` objects from somewhere.

Comment: @JonSkeet After taking your advice I have managed to get the program to work... but I have come across a new error... This is the new [`foreach`](https://gyazo.com/c751e8b456a5f6835b02b4c391ef8038) loop and [associated code](https://gyazo.com/b0559b0a3ec96965ef56b21f8f1917bf).

Comment: Please ask a new question if you really can't figure it out then - Stack Overflow isn't an interactive debugging session / helpdesk. It's intended to be a repository of high quality questions and answers.